# How to break gridview columns into different rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that binds up to 36 columns. This, of course, looks very bad.

I tried to set all of the columns to itemTemplates and divide then into rows. The problem is that my header titles are not fixed.

I also tried using CSS on my boundfields, but it definitely didnt work.

Thats what i have

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsGv1"  CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" OnPreRender="Gv1_PreRender">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr1" HeaderText="vr1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr1" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr2" HeaderText="vr2" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr2" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr3" HeaderText="vr3" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr3" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr4" HeaderText="vr4" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr4" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr5" HeaderText="vr5" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr5" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr6" HeaderText="vr6" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr6" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr7" HeaderText="vr7" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr7" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr8" HeaderText="vr8" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr8" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr9" HeaderText="vr9" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr9" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr10" HeaderText="vr10" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr10" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr11" HeaderText="vr11" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr11" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr12" HeaderText="vr12" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr12" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr13" HeaderText="vr13" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr13" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr14" HeaderText="vr14" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr14" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr15" HeaderText="vr15" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr15" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr16" HeaderText="vr16" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr16" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr17" HeaderText="vr17" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr17" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr18" HeaderText="vr18" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr18" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr19" HeaderText="vr19" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr19" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr20" HeaderText="vr20" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr20" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr21" HeaderText="vr21" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr21" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr22" HeaderText="vr22" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr22" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr23" HeaderText="vr23" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr23" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr24" HeaderText="vr24" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr24" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr25" HeaderText="vr25" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr25" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr26" HeaderText="vr26" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr26" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr27" HeaderText="vr27" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr27" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr28" HeaderText="vr28" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr28" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr29" HeaderText="vr29" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr29" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr30" HeaderText="vr30" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr30" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr31" HeaderText="vr31" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr31" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr32" HeaderText="vr32" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr32" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr33" HeaderText="vr33" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr33" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr34" HeaderText="vr34" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr34" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr35" HeaderText="vr35" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr35" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr36" HeaderText="vr36" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr36" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="vr_total" HeaderText="Valor Total" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vr_total" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

and here is the code that changes my headers

```
for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count-1; i++)
            {
                gv.Columns[i].HeaderText = dt.AddMonths(-11+i).ToString("MM/yyyy"); 
            }
```

So.. I have this

vr01 | vr02 | vr03 | vr04 | vr05 | vr06 | vr07 | vr08 | vr09 | vr10 | vr11 | vr12 | vr13 | vr14 | vr15 | vr16 | vr17 | vr18 | vr19 | vr20 | vr21 | vr22 | vr23 | vr24

I am looking for something like this:

vr01 | vr02 | vr03 | vr04 | vr05 | vr06 | vr07 | vr08 | vr09 | vr10 | vr11 | vr12

vr13 | vr14 | vr15 | vr16 | vr17 | vr18 | vr19 | vr20 | vr21 | vr22 | vr23 | vr24
...

Any advices?

Comment: So if the data source has 10 actual rows of data, the grid would display it in 20 rows? Sounds potentially confusing for the user, as it could be hard to distinguish whether a value is in the first column or the thirteenth. I suppose if you needed to, though, you might be able to do so by re-forming the data source, perhaps through a SQL view, stored procedure or whatever's appropriate to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pertinent to your question (w/business logic a bit unclear), the easiest way will be just place two `GridView` objects bound to the same `DataSource` but having different Columns, so the first `GridView` will have:

```
vr01 | vr02 | vr03 | vr04 | vr05 | vr06 | vr07 | vr08 | vr09 | vr10 | vr11 | vr12
```

and a second `GridView` placed below will have the rest Columns:

```
vr13 | vr14 | vr15 | vr16 | vr17 | vr18 | vr19 | vr20 | vr21 | vr22 | vr23 | vr24 ...
```

Alternatively, you may have just a single `GridView` and create a `TemplateField` with Columns arranged per your task. Hope this may hep.

Comment: Perfect!!! I am new to programming. I didnt know i could split data into different gridviews... Works as I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an `asp:DataList` and set `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"` and `RepeatColumns="12"`

MSDN Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatdirection(v=vs.110).aspx